# Automatically run a LaTeX3 function on the document environment

Tags: latex3

Is it possible to define a package so that it will automatically run a LaTeX3 function on the entirety of the `document` environment?

If I define a function similar to the following:

```
\cs_new:Npn \demo #1 {
    % Do something.
}
```

I would normally have to wrap it around the text as follows:

```
\demo{Some example text.}
```

Is it possible to instruct the `\demo` function to affect the whole `document` environment?

Comment: Yes, you can use `\AtBeginDocument`.  See for instance [How to automatically add text immediately after \begin{document}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14135/how-to-automatically-add-text-immediately-after-begindocument).

Comment: What would be the best way of making that work with a function similar to the above? 
`\AtBeginDocument{\demo{}` paired with `\AtEndDocument{}}` does not work due to the syntax.

Comment: To provide the context, I assume you are trying to apply a function such as the one in [Defining a find and replace algorithm using LaTeX3's l3regex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88394/defining-a-find-and-replace-algorithm-using-latex3s-l3regex).

Comment: If the problem is connected to the question cyberSingularity links to, then filtering the document with a scripting language such as Perl or Python would be a better choice. Reading a whole document for doing some replacement would be *deadly* slow.

Answer (score 5):

This question is not specific to LaTeX3, as it is a more general issue about how arguments are grabbed by TeX and the wrappers that LaTeX then provides.

Grabbing an argument in the form `\demo{Some text}` means that TeX has to read everything before it processes it. At the same time, there is a simple rule for the parsing: count the braces and read until they balance. For environments, that's not the same: TeX does *not* need to grab all of the environment in one go, so there is a lot less memory usage. (Even with a modern TeX, grabbing an entire document might well be too much.) The way that the beginning and end of environments work therefore does not directly rely on 'count the start/end pairs'.

It is possible to grab all of a LaTeX environment as an argument: packages such as [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) wrap this up into a package. However, I would not use this for applying some change to an entire document. Instead, I would use the approach we see with font switching commands, where each one which takes an argument (*e.g.* `\emph`) is accompanied by one that applies in an 'ongoing' sense (*e.g.* `\itshape`).

Answer (score 4):

As Josephs stated, this is probably not a good idea for a large document.

But, as I mentioned in the comments, you can use [the `environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) to collect the `\BODY` of the document starting `\AtBeginDocument` through to `\AtEndDocument`. Then, this `\BODY` can be passed to the desired macro.

The following applies the macro `\ApplyToEntireDocument` which simply applies `\textcolor{red}{}` to the entire document.

[image]

If possible, it would be better to apply the desired changes within the environment as opposed to calling yet another macro.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\ApplyToEntireDocument}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\NewEnviron{CollectBody}{%
    \ApplyToEntireDocument{\BODY}%
}%

\AtBeginDocument{\CollectBody}
\AtEndDocument{\endCollectBody}


\begin{document}
This is the start of the document.

Here is a well know equation:
\[
    E = mc^2
\]

And another paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Comment: My point would stand here as simply `\color{red}` would achieve the same thing (`\textcolor` uses `\color` internally).

Comment: Yep, totally agree. The reason I used `\textcolor` in the MWE was to illustrate that one could pass the `\BODY` to a macro as a parameter.