# Censoring Curse Words with Grawlixes

Tags: macros, symbols, strings, xstring

Suppose that I would like to censor a curse word `<word>` using [grawlixes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86838/what-the-is-that-called), e.g. "What the #@$! are you doing?!" How can I define a command `\censor` such that `\censor{<word>}` results in a string of these symbols? I am not entirely sure which or how many symbols should be used given the word `<word>`. I suppose that the number of symbols used should approximately equal the number of characters in `<word>`.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: It is _much_ easier to do that in the text editor source than in TeX. (luatex is probably easier than classical tex if you really want to do it at the text level) (It is easy enough to do it in restricted text contexts but hard if you need to do it in arbitrary paragraphs and lists etc)

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88394/defining-a-find-and-replace-algorithm-using-latex3s-l3regex

Comment: Irrelevant: Censorship always reinforces the actual word.

Comment: @percusse Yeah, this is mostly for the typographic effect rather than to try to actually censor the word.

Comment: @percusse I #@$!&%? !%$@ !%$.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Do same symbols represent same letters?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina [Can I buy a vowel?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/44j2v.jpg)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `\makeatletter` T@*(% !%$ .

Comment: Well, at least I learned [a new word](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grawlix) today.  But why isn't the plural *grawlices*?

Comment: Can you make a command which substitutes the ascii value x of each letter by, say (x mod 10) + 33.  This might be doable with the commands `\number` and `\char`, but I don't know how.  This will give "fuck" the new word "#(*(".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A random symbol is taken from a list and appended to a token list; when the width of the accumulated symbols is more than the width of the word minus 2pt, the symbols are printed, otherwise another symbol is appended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,pgf}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\censor}{m}
 {
  \pointer_censor:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_pointer_grawlixes_seq
\tl_map_inline:nn { @ * \# ! \$ \% ? ! \# @ \% *}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_pointer_grawlixes_seq { #1 }
 }
\int_const:Nn \c_pointer_grawlix_list_int { \seq_count:N \g_pointer_grawlixes_seq }

\dim_new:N \l_pointer_censor_dim
\dim_new:N \l_pointer_try_dim
\box_new:N \l_pointer_censor_box
\tl_new:N \l_pointer_grawlixes_tl


\cs_new_protected:Npn \pointer_censor:n #1
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_pointer_grawlixes_tl
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_pointer_censor_box { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_pointer_censor_dim { \box_wd:N \l_pointer_censor_box }
  \pointer_add_grawlix:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pointer_add_grawlix:
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_pointer_censor_box { \l_pointer_grawlixes_tl }
  \dim_compare:nTF
   { \l_pointer_censor_dim - 2pt < \box_wd:N \l_pointer_censor_box }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_pointer_grawlixes_tl
   }
   {
    \pgfmathparse{random(1,\int_eval:n {\c_pointer_grawlix_list_int})}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_pointer_grawlixes_tl
     { \seq_item:Nn \g_pointer_grawlixes_seq { \pgfmathresult } }
    \pointer_add_grawlix:
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Censored

\censor{Censored}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 18):

A humble attempt with `lualatex`:

<sup>The replacement code is very naive, we would need something more robust.</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{

% my list of bad words
bad_words = { "fish", "cat", "dog", "horse", "alligator" }

% the replacement string
replacement = "duck"

% a replacement function which returns
% both the altered line and the number
% of occurrences
function replace(line)
    for _, element in pairs(bad_words) do
        if string.find(line, element) then
            return string.gsub(line, element, replacement)
        end
    end
    return line, 0
end

% my "naive" censor function, it simply
% replaces any occurrences of the
% list of bad words by the replacement
% string
function censor(line)
    occurrences = 0
    repeat
        line, occurrences = replace(line)
    until occurrences == 0
    return line
end

% add the hook
callback.register('process_input_buffer', censor)}

\begin{document}

Once upon a time, there was a little cat who lived inside an igloo. Don't ask me what he was doing there.

One day, the cat was visited by his two other friends, the dog and the alligator!

--- ``What are you guys doing here?'', said the cat.

--- ``We came to visit you, mr.\ cat!'', said the dog.

--- ``Our friend horse will be late, he went to the store to buy some frozen fish for you``, replied the alligator.

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: More ducks]

**Moral of the story:** I'm terrible at telling stories. `:)`

Now, let's add the grawlixes. Since I need a better Lua code, let's create an external file `censor.lua` and call it from out `.tex` code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{censor.lua}
-- a list of symbols to represent the
-- grawlixe symbols
-- note that we need to escape
-- some chars
grawlixe_symbols = { "\\$", "\\#", "@", "!", "*", "\\&" }

-- generate a grawlixe of length s
-- note that the seed is not so random, so
-- same values of s might get the same
-- grawlixe pattern (I could add another seed
-- mid code, but I'm lazy)
function grawlixe(s)
    math.randomseed(os.time())
    local u = table.getn(grawlixe_symbols)
    local i = math.random(u)
    local r = grawlixe_symbols[i]
    local current
    local w = 1
    repeat
        current = math.random(u)
        while current == i do
            current = math.random(u)
        end
        i = current
        r = r .. grawlixe_symbols[i]
        w = w + 1
    until w == s
    return r
end

-- a list of bad words to be censored
bad_words = { "fish", "cat", "dog", "horse", "alligator" }

-- our replacement function, it returns
-- the new line and the number of
-- replacements made
-- note that this is a very naive replacement
-- function, there's a lot of room for
-- improvement
function replace(line)
    for _, element in pairs(bad_words) do
        if string.find(line, element) then
        return string.gsub(line, element, grawlixe(string.len(element)))
        end
    end
    return line, 0
end

-- the censor function, it repeats
-- ad nauseam until the line has
-- nothing more to be censored
function censor(line)
    local occurrences = 0
    repeat
        line, occurrences = replace(line)
    until occurrences == 0
    return line
end

-- register the callback
callback.register('process_input_buffer', censor)
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\directlua{dofile('censor.lua')}

\begin{document}

Once upon a time, there was a little cat who lived inside an igloo. Don't ask me what he was doing there.

One day, the cat was visited by his two other friends, the dog and the alligator!

--- ``What are you guys doing here?'', said the cat.

--- ``We came to visit you, mr.\ cat!'', said the dog.

--- ``Our friend horse will be late, he went to the store to buy some frozen fish for you``, replied the alligator.

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Grawlixes]

**Moral of the new story:** adding grawlixes to a text makes it look naughty. `:)`

Comment: +1 (even though I hoped to see a duck picture, perhaps it was censored?)

Answer (score 13):

Leaving aside the pros and cons of how and why to do this, I find it a nice little exercise to do with [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring). So here's my take on it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\def\grawlix{{\makeatletter@\makeatother}\textdollar{$\sharp$}*?!}

\newcommand{\censor}[1]{\StrLen{#1}[\result]%
\expandarg\StrLeft{\grawlix}{\result}[]}

\begin{document}
What the \censor{word} is this???
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the limitation is that the grawlix will be composed of the same set of characters, in the same order. (You may redefine the character set or find a way to randomize them at each invocation of the macro... but that's a different story! `;)`) But your grawlix will be as long as the censored word.

What happens is that `xstring` has his own ways of expanding arguments and the macros cannot be nested. So the result from the macro that finds the length of the censored word is returned in a different macro (imaginatively called here `\result`) that will be (re)used to split the predefined `\grawlix` at the right spot.

The `\expandarg` macro makes sure the expansion is done properly. According to `xstring` documentation, it will allow all arguments passed to be expanded *exactly* once. Therefore, care must be taken to protect groups that represent a *single* character with braces (e.g. the `\sharp` symbol lives in mathmode, but we don't want the dollar signs delimiting it to be seen as separate tokens).

Comment: I don't think `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are necessary around the @... It can be used as the symbol it is right away.

Comment: @cgnieder It's a good job they are not necessary as they have no effect at all if used _inside_ the definition as here:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle true, I hadn't thought about that... I need more coffee

Answer (score 12):

A plain TeX solution without additional packages, based on ideas of Kees van der Laan.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcount\cur
\newcount\cura

\def\fifo#1{\ifx\ofif#1\ofif\fi
\process#1\fifo}
\def\ofif#1\fifo{\fi}

\def\mynum#1{\cur\the\lccode`#1\relax\the\cur }

\def\process#1{\cur\the\lccode`#1\relax\cura\cur \divide\cura by7 \multiply\cura by7
    \advance\cur by-\cura\ifcase\cur!\or@\or\#\or\$\or\%\or\&\or*\else  ERROR\fi }

\fifo censored \ofif

\bigskip

\def\censor#1{\fifo #1\ofif}

\censor{fuck}
\censor{WORD}
it is
\censor{shit}

\end{document}
```

You probably want to have the result connected with the word used. In this solution it is `\lccode` of a character modulo 7. You can write either

```
    \fifo censored \ofif
```

or, as suggested (sorry for my language),

```
\censor{fuck}
\censor{WORD}
it is
\censor{shit}
```

obtaining

[image]

Some explanations.
The main tool is the implemantation of FIFO (First-In-First-Out) queue 
suggested by Kees van der Laan:

```
\def\fifo#1{\ifx\ofif#1\ofif\fi
    \process#1\fifo}
    \def\ofif#1\fifo{\fi}
```

The `\fifo` command calls a macro `\process` that
handles the individual arguments. Every token is processed
until `\ofif`.

The rest is simple. Manipulating on the counters `\cur` and `\cura` we obtain a number between 0 and 6 and `\ifcase` takes different censor characters for different values.

**Remark.** I am very interested of the real rules (if they exist) of replacing curse words by strings of @-like symbols.

Comment: Very nice. Could you perhaps expand (pardon the pun) a bit on how the code actually works?

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, but after returning home (at late evening).

Comment: `\censor{MSWORD}`

Answer (score 7):

A stable way to exchange symbols is to change the fontencoding or to reencode the font. A simple example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\censor[1]{\fontencoding{OMS}\selectfont #1}
\censor{Censored}
\end{document}
```

With lualatex it will in the future (when the interface is more stable) be probably be possible to create virtual reencoded fonts on-the-fly, currently it should be already possible to do it with a feature file.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension to @egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117835/10995) using another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200382/10995) by @egreg.

With this code you can enter a whole sentence in `\censor` and all words initially added to a list using `\addcensor` are replaced by grawlixes. The argument to `\addcensor` can be either a single word or a comma separated list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,pgf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\censor}{m}
 {
  \pointer_badseq:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \g_pointer_badwords_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\addcensor}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_pointer_badwords_tl { {##1}{} }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnTF { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pointer_badseq:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \str_case:nVTF { ##1 } \g_pointer_badwords_tl
     { \pointer_censor:n { ##1 } } { ##1 } ~ % Readd space
   }
  \tex_unskip:D % Remove the trailing space
 }

% From @egreg's answer
\seq_new:N \g_pointer_grawlixes_seq
\tl_map_inline:nn { @ * \# ! \$ \% ? ! \# @ \% *}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_pointer_grawlixes_seq { #1 }
 }
\int_const:Nn \c_pointer_grawlix_list_int { \seq_count:N \g_pointer_grawlixes_seq }

\dim_new:N \l_pointer_censor_dim
\dim_new:N \l_pointer_try_dim
\box_new:N \l_pointer_censor_box
\tl_new:N \l_pointer_grawlixes_tl


\cs_new_protected:Npn \pointer_censor:n #1
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_pointer_grawlixes_tl
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_pointer_censor_box { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_pointer_censor_dim { \box_wd:N \l_pointer_censor_box }
  \pointer_add_grawlix:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pointer_add_grawlix:
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_pointer_censor_box { \l_pointer_grawlixes_tl }
  \dim_compare:nTF
   { \l_pointer_censor_dim - 2pt < \box_wd:N \l_pointer_censor_box }
   {
    \tl_use:N \l_pointer_grawlixes_tl
   }
   {
    \pgfmathparse{random(1,\int_eval:n {\c_pointer_grawlix_list_int})}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_pointer_grawlixes_tl
     { \seq_item:Nn \g_pointer_grawlixes_seq { \pgfmathresult } }
    \pointer_add_grawlix:
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addcensor{censored,duck}
\addcensor{street}

\begin{document}
A censored man walk down the street together with his duck.

\censor{A censored man walk down the street together with his duck}.
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: It annoys me when you use traditional placing of open and closing brace (open brace adjacent to the function, then new line, then the code, and then the closing brace alone in a new line —without indent—), mixing it with the recommended LaTeX3 way (both alone on a new line, indented the same amount of space).

Comment: @Manuel Sorry, I hope my updated answer fits the recommended style.

Comment: Definetly better (IMO). I like this way, even now that I'm reading ConTeXt source code and it writes completely different (at least they don't use the opening brace, new line, code, new line closing brace without indentation too much, but something more like `%`, new line, opening brace and code, more code, and closing brace next to the code).