# Replace instances of \cite that have a specific argument

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, citing

In LaTeX, is there a way to define a macro (or something) to replace every instance of

```
\cite{a_literal_string}
```

with

```
\ref{appendix:a_different_literal_string}
```

without touching instances of `\cite` with arguments that aren't `a_literal_string`? I would like to do this for several different possible replacements.

The idea here is that I'm including some modular documents in a larger project, and I want to use some of them as appendices. I don't want to just find/replace, because the sub-documents need to be able to refer to each other when they aren't being used in the larger project.

Comment: Will Find and replace work?

Comment: Nah. The idea is to do this for files which are being included via \subimport, and to only make the change in one particular document which is including them. I will add this to the question.

Comment: `\renewcommand\cite[1]{\ref{appendix:#1}}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke: This redefines *all* uses of `\cite`, which is not what is asked for in the question.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an implementation with `expl3` and `xparse`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cite:a,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={Title a},
 journal={J. A},
 year={2014},
}
@article{cite:b,
 author={B. Athor},
 title={Title b},
 journal={J. B},
 year={2014},
}
@article{cite:c,
 author={C. Ethor},
 title={Title c},
 journal={J. C},
 year={2014},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\latexcite}{\cite}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{om}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   { \daniel_cite_or_ref:n { #2 } }
   { \latexcite[#1]{#2} }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addsubstitution}{mm}
 {
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_daniel_changes_tl { {#1}{\ref{#2}} }
 }

\tl_new:N \g_daniel_changes_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \daniel_cite_or_ref:n #1
 {
  \str_case:nVTF { #1 } \g_daniel_changes_tl
  {
   % \nocite{#1} %%%% <---- uncomment this line if you want \nocite
  }
  {
   \latexcite{#1}
  }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnTF { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addsubstitution{cite:a}{ref:a}
\addsubstitution{cite:b}{ref:b}

\begin{document}

\section{Something}\label{sec:some}

Here we do the citations: \cite{cite:a}, \cite{cite:b}, 
\cite{cite:c} and \cite[p.~42]{cite:c}

\appendix

\section{First appendix}\label{ref:a}

Text

\section{Second appendix}\label{ref:b}

Text

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

You're supposed to use just one item in a `\cite` command; taking into account multiple citations with substitutions is possible, but it requires a decision about the final format.

With the `\addsubstitution` command you add the substitutions you want to do: the first argument is the citation key, the second argument is the label.

In the references only the actually cited items are inserted; if you want to add also the items that you substitute, it's sufficient to uncomment `\nocite` in the macros above.

[image]

### Note on the implementation

The `expl3` function `\str_case:nnTF` takes four arguments:

1. the string to check;
2. a set of pairs `{<string>}{<action>}`;
3. what to do if a match is found;
4. what to do if no match is found.

With the variant `\str_case:nVTF`, the second argument is a token list variable that contains the set of pairs.

The new `\cite` command will use the original `\cite` if the optional argument is given; otherwise it passes control to `\daniel_cite_or_ref:n` that checks the argument against the set of pairs stored in `\g_daniel_changes_tl`; this variable is populated by any number of `\addsubstitution` commands.

It would be easy, albeit not straightforward, to add other features, for instance accepting multiple keys in the argument of `\cite` and deciding what to do when a key needs the substitution.

Answer (score 7):

If you're willing to use LuaLaTeX, your objective can be achieved using Lua's powerful `string.gsub` function. In the example below, the Lua-side code is stored in a file called `string_replacements.lua`. (For anything but the most trivial cases, it's usually easiest to store the Lua code in a separate file and to call it with a `\directlua{ require("string_replacements.lua")}` directive.) The function `replace_string` can perform multiple string replacements. Is is assigned to the `process_input_buffer` callback, which does its job *before* any processing by LaTeX takes place; the contents of the input file are not modified.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexbase}
\directlua{require("string_replacements.lua")}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
Here's a cross-reference to Appendix \cite{a_literal_string}. 
And here's a cross-reference to abcdefuvwxyz.

\appendix
\section{Good-bye} \label{appendix:a_different_literal_string}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:pyth}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The contents of `string_replacements.lua` are:

```
-- string_replacements.lua
   local function replace_string ( line )
       line = string.gsub ( line, 
           "\\cite{a_literal_string}" , 
           "\\ref{appendix:a_different_literal_string}" )
       line = string.gsub ( line,
           "abcdefuvwxyz",
           "equation~(\\ref{eq:pyth})" )
       return line
   end
   luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", 
       replace_string, "replace_string" )
```

Comment: Interesting, but just one substitution is supported.

Comment: Indeed, I am looking for multiple substitutions. I will edit OP.

Comment: @DanielSank - I've updated the example to show how perform multiple string replacements.

Comment: wow...seems pretty dangerous though...to what does the substitution apply exactly? Does it also substitute comment strings? What about things in verbatim? I know having `\verb|\cite{a_literal_string}|` in the same doc is unrealistic but I'm interested in the general case...

Comment: @Bordaigorl - "seems pretty dangerous though" -- Why? As already noted, function in the `process_input_buffer` callback *operate on all material* in the input stream, *before* any processing by TeX takes place. If the OP wants the string `a_literal_string` replaced with `a_different_literal_string` *everywhere* in the document, I can only assume that this objective applies to verbatim material as well. Note that any substitutions inside comments remain commented out -- nothing dangerous there either, right?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
\def\speclabel#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname slab:#1\endcsname{#2}}
\let\citeOri=\cite
\def\cite#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname slab:#1\endcsname\relax\citeOri{#1}%
   \else \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ref
         \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname slab:#1\endcsname}\fi
}
\speclabel {a_literal_string}       {a_different_literal_string}
\speclabel {another_literal_strig}  {another_different_litral_string}

Now \cite{normal} behaves normal but \cite{a_literal_string} expands
to \ref{a_different_literal_string}.
```

You have to declare conversions by `\speclabel` macros and you can use normal `\cite`.

Comment: A pure LaTeX version would be `\protected\def\cite#1{\@ifundefined{slab:#1}{\citeOri{#1}}{\ref{\@nameuse{slab:#1}}}}`. I understand you want to be compatible with formats that also use `\cite` and `\ref`, but this is not good practice in my opinion. Of course, your code loses the optional argument to `\cite`.

Comment: @egreg The question doesn't include the word LaTeX. I don't know what format OP needs to use (and I don't understand why other posters know it). My answer is independent of used format (and I tested it only by plain TeX).

Comment: I thought Plain TeX hasn't `\cite` and `\ref`. Should I check the TeXbook?

Comment: TeX disposes of `\def`. So document can use arbitrary control sequences, `\cite` and `\ref` for example. You can check the chapter from TeXbook where the `\def` is described, if you want.

Comment: @egreg Don't remember `\protected` being using by `latex.ltx` ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright It should be `\DeclareRobustCommand` (but `\LetLtxMacro` must be used for defining `\citeOri`, as you surely know). This is handier; but definitely not Plain TeX.

Comment: As you are using e-TeX, perhaps `\expandafter\ifx\csname slab:#1\endcsname\relax` could be replaced by an `\ifcsname slab:#1\endcsname` test?

Comment: @JosephWright I've removed `\protected` from my code, then I am not using eTeX now.