# Is it possible to use the Chalkduster font in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex

I have followed the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621128/using-chalkduster-font-in-xelatex-correctly) to write a mwe:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Chalkduster} 
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
Is this what you expected?
\end{document}
```

It works well when compiled using xelatex:
[image: "Is this what you expected", written in Chalkduster font]
Whenever I switch the comment between the `documentclass` lines, this is what I get:
[image: "Is this what you expected", written in normal, not Chalkduster font]

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: beamer uses the sans font, so set \setsansfont

Comment: Yes, it works! thanks a lot